# Setup CodeMirror 6 with Angular 12

Tags: angular, codemirror, codemirror-6

As I'm trying to setup a editor in codemirror v6 with angular but having difficulties in set up as it differs from previous v5.X. Need help in setting up codemirror basic editor with angular. Thank you.

```
import {EditorState, EditorView, basicSetup} from "@codemirror/basic-setup";
import {javascript} from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  // Define var here...
  title = 'cEditor';
  @ViewChild('editor') editor: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editor = new EditorView({
      state: EditorState.create({
        extensions: [basicSetup, javascript()]
      }),
      parent: document.body
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You almost there,

Update import.

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { basicSetup} from "codemirror";
import { EditorState } from '@codemirror/state';
import { EditorView } from '@codemirror/view';
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

AfterViewInit is preferable to ngOnInit as there is work referencing the element.

And don't forget to declare `document` at constructor when you set parent with `body`

```js
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

That's it !!!.

---

This will help you as It did to me.
[CodeMirror 5 to 6 Migration Guide](https://codemirror.net/docs/migration/)

Also you can check this.

- [DEMO: codemirror6 with Angular 12 sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-uotxlw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
- [DEMO: codemirror6 with Angular 13 sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-qel5ft?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Please make sure as below before start:**

- @codemirror/basic-setup --> `npm install codemirror@6.0.1`
- [basicSetup](https://codemirror.net/docs/ref/#codemirror.basicSetup), This extension does not allow customization.